# How to disable next and previous buttons in MediaTransportControls (UWP)

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I am setting a playlist in `MediaPlayerElement` as follows, however I find that there is no way to disable `previous` or `next` track buttons.

[image: MediaPlayerElement's previous and next buttons]

What is more surprising the whole thing integrates very well with the OS level System Media Trasport Control, i.e previous and next button there are automatically disabled when I am at the first or last track.

[image: SMTC control view][image]

```xml
<MediaPlayerElement x:Name="MediaPlayerElement" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True">
    <MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
        <MediaTransportControls
            IsFullWindowButtonVisible="False"
            IsNextTrackButtonVisible="True"
            IsPreviousTrackButtonVisible="True"
            IsZoomButtonVisible="False" />
    </MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
</MediaPlayerElement>
```

```cs
var playbackList = new MediaPlaybackList();

var total = (uint)episodes.Count();

uint track = 0;
foreach (var episode in episodes)
{
    var mediaPlaybackItem = new MediaPlaybackItem(MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri(episode.MediaUrl)));

    var props = mediaPlaybackItem.GetDisplayProperties();
    props.Type = Windows.Media.MediaPlaybackType.Music;
    props.Thumbnail = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri(episode.ImageUrl));
    props.MusicProperties.Title = episode.Title;
    props.MusicProperties.Artist = episode.Author;
    props.MusicProperties.AlbumTrackCount = total;
    props.MusicProperties.TrackNumber = ++track;
    mediaPlaybackItem.ApplyDisplayProperties(props);
    playbackList.Items.Add(mediaPlaybackItem);
}

MediaPlayer.Source = playbackList;

mediaPlayerElement.SetMediaPlayer(MediaPlayer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify or completely override the behavior of the SMTC controls with the **MediaPlaybackCommandManager** class.Disable the next or previous command by setting the **EnablingRule** for the Next/Previous command to Never.For more details you can refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/integrate-with-systemmediatransportcontrols#use-commandmanager-to-modify-or-override-the-default-smtc-commands).

```
player.CommandManager.NextBehavior.EnablingRule = MediaCommandEnablingRule.Never;
player.CommandManager.PreviousBehavior.EnablingRule = MediaCommandEnablingRule.Never;
```

Comment: My issue is not with the SMTC, SMTC UI is working just fine (previous and next are disabled appropriately). It is the previous and next track buttons in the MediaPlayerElement in the UWP app that are not disabled.

Comment: I have updated the question with the snapshots of MediaPlayerElement and SMTC control. I am on 1803.

Comment: If you want to disable previous and next track buttons like the SMTC control(the color turns gray),native UWP control can't do this, it seems you need to custom a controller.

Comment: I extended the `MediaTransportControls` class and attempted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58282831/1139856). But it is still not working.