# Unable to update UWP UI from code behind using Dispatcher

Tags: uwp-xaml, dispatcher

I have a derived class from `MediaTransportControls` and trying to disable previous and next track buttons based on some events. I wrote following

```cs
public class MyMediaTransportControls : MediaTransportControls
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsPreviousTrackButtonEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IsPreviousTrackButtonEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(MyMediaTransportControls), new PropertyMetadata(false, IsPreviousTrackButtonEnabledChangedCallback));

    private static async void IsPreviousTrackButtonEnabledChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mediaTransportControls = d as MyMediaTransportControls;

        if(mediaTransportControls?.GetTemplateChild("PreviousTrackButton") is Button previousTrackButton)
        {
            await mediaTransportControls.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                previousTrackButton.IsEnabled = (bool)e.NewValue;
            });
        }
    }

    public bool IsPreviousTrackButtonEnabled
    {
        get { return (bool) GetValue(IsPreviousTrackButtonEnabledProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsPreviousTrackButtonEnabledProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

I have used data binding to bind `IsPreviousTrackButtonEnabled` with the ViewModel logic. However, I find that even when `previousTrackButton.IsEnabled` is set it has no impact on the UI. Sometime, though, when debuging, I can see the impact on UI.

**Update**

The `MediaTransportControls` provide its own `ControlTemplate` and I wish not to create my own template and do data binding with it.

Answer (score 0):

Write Notify Property Changed Event Handler

```
 INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is going to help. If I had control over the XAML then yes, I could use the data binding and INotifyPropertyChanged would help. However, I am extending a `MediaTransportControls`, it already has a Controltemplate. And I am not keen to change that, as Microsoft could change it in future.

Comment: If you have implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth) interface in your `ViewModel`,  `IsPreviousTrackButtonEnabled` dependency property will work.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Yes the view model implements the INotifyPropertyChanged and when the view model property changes it does set `IsPreviousTrackButtonEnabled` and invoke `IsPreviousTrackButtonEnabledChangedCallback`. However, `previousTrackButton.IsEnabled = (bool)e.NewValue;` code does not seem to disable the button. As I mentioned, some time it does, especially when debugging. Just wondering if I am using the dispatcher code correctly?

Comment: could share a mini sample that could reproduce your issue?